# What is a glass artificial horizon?

Tags: terminology, navigation, history

On Amundsen's polar expedition they had,

> Of instruments and apparatus for the sledge journeys we carried two sextants, **three artificial horizons**, of which two were **glass horizons with dark glasses,** and one a mercury horizon, and four spirit compasses, made in Christiania.

[The South Pole
An Account of the Norwegian Antarctic Expedition in the “Fram”, 1910–1912](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/a/amundsen/roald/southpole/complete.html)

You can see in this [answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/21455/8794) the team using the mercury artificial horizon, but **what is a glass horizon?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd suppose, that the glass horizon is the one that uses a well-polished glass as a reflective surface. The quote from the answer you've mentioned:

> The basic arrangement needs a horizontal reflective plane, for which
>   Amundsen used a pool of mercury. A **precisely weighted mirror** could
>   work also, but a pool of mercury is more robust and doesn't go out of
>   calibration.

The device could be seen at the website of [Royal Museums Greenwich](http://collections.rmg.co.uk/collections/objects/42231.html) where it's described as:

> A circular brass case on three levelling feet covered with a blackened
>   glass plate serving as mirror.

BTW, other glass artificial horizons exemplars could be found in the mentioned museum collection.

[image]

Comment: Interesting that they used a black glass, no a mirror. Would the be because its cheaper?

Comment: @PaulPaulsen I doubt that a mirror would be much more expensive. I'd assume that either a black glass could be better in some weather/atmospheric conditions or it would last longer than a mirror would - I mean that amalgam deterioration that could be seen on many old mirrors. But these are just rough assumptions.

Comment: It could also be to make the reflection of the sun less blinding. In black glass the suns reflection will be plenty visible, while a proper mirror might actually make it hard to get an accurate reading.

Comment: Another question that arises for me: how (by means of measuring) do you get that thing level. I cannot see any indicator to show the inclination.

Comment: @BenediktBauer As the description of the current item says (see the link to Royal Museums Greenwich) - "The spirit level is missing". So at least we should expect a sort of a measuring device to be used together with the horizon.